# Vector mat in txt

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, mat

I ve got a vector Mat file and I want to store it in txt file. Every mat file has size 1x4500 and I ve got in total 5000 vectors. I tried to store in txtfile with the above code:

```
void writeMatToFile(cv::Mat& m, const char* filename){

ofstream fout(filename);
for(int i=0; i<m.rows; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<m.cols; j++){
        fout<<m.at<float>(i,j)<<"\t";
    }
    fout<<endl;
}
fout.close();
```

}

In main:

```
    string file = "output.txt";
writeMatToFile(image,file.c_str());
```

However, I got unhandled exception errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your data in binary mode using your own format. Something like : `mat_count|shape1|data1(row_first)|shape2...`

`std::fstream` will do the harder job for you in text mode or binary mode. You should try both to see the final size.

If your Mat data is something like `uint8`, `uint16`, the binary mode will be much better. The problem with text-mode is that you need a separator for each single data which add additional bytes to your file. However text-mode can compress data : "1.5" 3 vs 8 bytes (double).

Last thing, if you want absolutely a file in text-mode, you can zip it at the end of your process and see the ratio.